# Kinesis sent records is not equal to consumed records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We are evaluating Kinesis and I found following behaviors. I have simple test using Kinesis for testing accuracy and basic functionality.

The test produces item into a Stream as follows:

```
    PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
    putRecordRequest.setStreamName( streamName );
    putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(event.getBytes()));
    putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey( message.getEventList().getEvents().get(0).getLicenseKey());

    UsageServiceStatistics.instance().getKinesisSent().increase();
    PutRecordResult putRecordResult = kinesisManager.getConnection().putRecord( putRecordRequest );
```

Then I use Amazon Kinesis client library (KCL) as follows:

```
@Override
public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer iRecordProcessorCheckpointer)
{
    logger.debug("Received a list of records for processing with size:" + records.size());

    for (Record record : records)
    {
        UsageServiceStatistics.instance().getKinesisConsumed().increase();
        logger.debug("Kinesis consumed:" + UsageServiceStatistics.instance().getKinesisConsumed());
        if (!processRecord(record))
        {
            logger.error("Couldn't process record " + record + ". Skipping the record.");
        }
    }

    checkpointManager.checkpoint(iRecordProcessorCheckpointer);
}
```

I am seeing discrepancies between the number of produced versus the number of consumed record.
For example when sending series of 2000 items 3 times in a row i see the following:

```
Kinesis sent:counter=2000
Kinesis consumed:1999

Kinesis sent:counter=4000
Kinesis consumed:counter=3994

Kinesis sent:counter=6000
Kinesis consumed:counter=5999
```

Why I don't see the exact same number of produced vs consumed ?
Why after the second run 6 items were missing, and i got 2006 consumed records at run 3 only although i waited at least 2 mn between run 2 and run 3.

Finally, I did a set of test before this one with a higher frequency of checkpointing and then the discrepancies were even bigger? What is the rule Amazon KCL uses to trigger the sending of records to a conumer? Why would it stop sending and keep items in the queue(like from run 2 to 3)? Where is the last item of the 6000 that were sent?

Thx in advance

Comment: Did you check for exceptions on the event writing to Kinesis. You might have be throttled for some of the put_record calls.

Comment: I did check and there are no exceptions even when putting the kinesis log level to debug.

Comment: How did you put the kinesis log level to debug. Can you please post the steps/sample you made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause.

That was a bug in my code.

The KCL creates a number of Record Processors that is equal to the number of shards in the particular stream.

However, I introduced a bug by having them using the same Checkpointer entity in a multi-threaded environment.
When I fixed it to have each record processor having its own checkpointer, it worked perfectly and the counts were consistent.